# What is the order to use sap template?

Tags: angular, asp.net-core, .net-core, angular-cli

.net core + angular template.

```
 if (env.IsDevelopment())
    {
      spa.UseAngularCliServer(npmScript: "start");
      spa.Options.StartupTimeout = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(600);
    }
```

Or

```
 if (env.IsDevelopment())
    {
      spa.Options.StartupTimeout = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(600);
      spa.UseAngularCliServer(npmScript: "start");
    }
```

I changed the order of startuptimeout. So which one is the right one?

Answer (score 0):

**SpaOptions.StartupTimeout** : Gets or sets the maximum duration that a request will wait for the SPA to become ready to serve to the client.

**UseAngularCliServer method** : Handles requests by passing them through to an instance of the Angular CLI server. This means you can always serve up-to-date CLI-built resources without having to run the Angular CLI server manually.This feature should only be used in development. For production deployments, be sure not to enable the Angular CLI serve .

They are all in `Microsoft.AspNetCore.SpaServices.Extensions` assembly , but `UseAngularCliServer` is one of Extension Methods in [ISpaBuilder](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.aspnetcore.spaservices.ispabuilder?view=aspnetcore-2.2) Interface  which defines a class that provides mechanisms for configuring the hosting of a Single Page Application (SPA) and attaching middleware.

The correct order should be like what Tony Ngo said .

```
if (env.IsDevelopment())
    {
        spa.Options.StartupTimeout = new TimeSpan(days: 0, hours: 0, minutes: 1, seconds: 30);
        spa.UseAngularCliServer(npmScript: "start");
    }
```